# How to add more functionality in CreateUser method ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed a website in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ASP.Net and MVC4. I have also users account management functionality enabled which is default from `visual studio`. When I call the "Create User" methods, I found the following method

```
  membershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email,
     model.SecretQuestion, model.SecretAnswer, false, out createStatus);
```

This method only adds columns to the database for password, email, etc. I want to add the users company name, last and first name and telephone number etc. When I see into the class IMembership, This class is locked and I can not make any change.

```
 #region Assembly SecurityGuard.dll, v4.0.30319
 // C:\Users\wwwimc\Desktop\WebFrontEnd_26012014\packages\SecurityGuard.MVC4.1.0.10   
 \lib\net40\SecurityGuard.dll
 #endregion

using System;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace SecurityGuard.Interfaces
{
   public interface IMembershipService
  {
    string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    bool EnablePasswordReset { get; }
    bool EnablePasswordRetrieval { get; }
    string HashAlgorithmType { get; }
    int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts { get; }
    int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters { get; }
    int MinRequiredPasswordLength { get; }
    int PasswordAttemptWindow { get; }
    string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression { get; }
    MembershipProvider Provider { get; }
    MembershipProviderCollection Providers { get; }
    bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer { get; }
    int UserIsOnlineTimeWindow { get; }

    event MembershipValidatePasswordEventHandler ValidatingPassword;

    MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password);
    MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email);
    MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, out MembershipCreateStatus status);
    MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status);
    bool DeleteUser(string username);
    bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData);
    MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch);
    MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
    MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch);
    MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
    string GeneratePassword(int length, int numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters);
    MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers();
    MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
    int GetNumberOfUsersOnline();
    MembershipUser GetUser();
    MembershipUser GetUser(bool userIsOnline);
    MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey);
    MembershipUser GetUser(string username);
    MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline);
    MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline);
    string GetUserNameByEmail(string emailToMatch);
    void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user);
    bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);
}
```

}

Could anybody suggest any way to make the changes so that with new registration, I could add the more information about the user?

Comment: Its just an interface, why not create an interface that inherits from this one, and extends it with the information you want?

Comment: @paqogomez Yes this is an interface but it should be inherited or implemented already somewhere for the purpose of implementation?. I guess I would need to make so many changes if I inherit this and implement a new class just for FirstName, LastName, Company, and Telephone. Cant I just these 4 variables into current implemetntion?

Comment: @paqogomez I am thinking to overload **CreateUser** method with my four new parameters.

Comment: The `CreateUser` methods are not virtual, so you cannot overload them specifically.  But creating a new method and calling the base class does the same thing and allows you to extend all the functionality.

Comment: If you are worried about changing all the instanciation calls in your current code, i'm afraid that you'd have to do that all anyway.

Comment: It would be great if `MembershipService` was implemented as a partial class, then you could just extend it w/ no changes to your current code.  But it is not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your own class to extend SecurityGuard's `MembershipService`

```
using System.Web.Security;
using SecurityGuard.Services;

namespace MyMembershipNamespace
{
    public class MyMembershipService : MembershipService
    {
        public MyMembershipService(MembershipProvider membershipProvider)
        : base(membershipProvider)
        {
        }

        public MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string company, string phone)
        {
            //Add code here to save company and phone to the database

            //allow base to execute normally
            return base.CreateUser(username, password, email);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create class what you want to ADD property
then you set that class object as

```
object providerUserKey

public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string userName, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
```

get this object value and set Linq(Add) for it.